# The set of the ideals of $\mathbb{C}$ corresponding to the points of complex geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

There is parallel relation between the ideals over $\mathbb{C}$ corresponding to the  points of complex geometry  and the ideals of the field of the complex function, now how to construct the ideals over $\mathbb{C}$?

please see the following comment for more precise and general clear statement.

And then how to construct the ideals over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The right statement is that there is a bijection between *maximal* ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and points in $\mathbb{C}$ given by $(x- \alpha) \mapsto \alpha$. More generally, there is a bijection between maximal ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$ and points in $\mathbb{C}^n$ given by $(x_1-\alpha_1,...,x_n- \alpha_n) \mapsto (\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and I will update my post.

Comment: What do you mean by how to construct the ideals over $\mathbb{C}$? My comment above tells you exactly what form they're in

Comment: I mean the complex number field $\mathbb{C}$ has ideals corresponding to  ideals of the $\mathbb{C[x]}$, but I do not know how to construct ideals of the complex number field $\mathbb{C}$ when we know the ideals of the $\mathbb{C[x]}$. You know complex number may be regarded as function of the ideals of the complex number field $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Every field has precisely two ideals, the zero ideal and the unit ideal, no more no less (check this).

Comment: What said leibnewtz is what appeals your "question" : a field has only two ideals. Points of $\mathbb{C}^n$ are maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, ie. points of $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$ (this lead to the Zariski topology and to the topology on the spectrum of a ring). The second step is that something similar holds for compact Riemann surfaces (whose field of meromorphic functions is also the function field of some algebraic variety $\subset \mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^n$)